# Event listener for safari on iOS

Tags: ios, safari

Goal: I’d like to create a simple webpage for iOS safari that “listens” for changes on the server.

For example: when sales for the month exceed $100, the background color will change to green.

The problem is that I don’t know the proper name for this type of functionality. And I also don’t know what technology will support this. I’ve tried my best to research this. Can this be achieved with JavaScript? Or do I need to look into PWA or node-js?

If anyone can tell me the proper name for this functionality or what technology I should begin with, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there are any examples or demos available online, please share.  I’m trying to start simple or with a proof of concept and build from there.